# Advanced Custom Fields Repeater Not displaying second image on second Upload

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a custom theme in WP using ACF. I am using a repeater to post images. The repeater code just works fine for the first image I post but for some reason when I upload the second image, it does not display on the front page.

```
                                <?php if( have_rows('latest1') ): ?>

                                    <div class="row">

                                    <?php while( have_rows('latest1') ): the_row(); 

                                        $image = get_sub_field('image');
                                        $title = get_sub_field('title');
                                        $news = get_sub_field('news');
                                        $more = get_sub_field('more');
                                        $date = get_sub_field('date');
                                    ?>

                                    <!-- REPEATING SEGMENT -->

                                  <div class="col-md-2">
                                      <a href="wrk-AboutUS.html" class="img-news-container">
                                          <img src="<?php echo $image["url"];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
                                      </a>
                                  </div>

                                  <div id="primary3" class="content-area col-md-7 no-padding-right">
                                      <main id="main3" class="site-main " >
                                          <article class="item-lastest-news itemBlogList">



                                              <div class="">
                                                  <a href="wrk-AboutUS.html"><h4 class="title-news"><?php echo $title; ?></h4></a>
                                                  <div class="">

                                                      <span class="dates" style="color:green;"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <p> <?php echo $news; ?></p>

                                                  <a class="continueReading" href="<?php echo $link ?>"><span style="color: brown;">Continue Reading</span></a>
                                                  <hr>
                                              </div> <!-- End Text box -->
                                          </article><!-- End Arcicle -->
                                      </main>

                                  </div>
                                    <!-- REPEATING SEGMENT -->


                                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                                    </div> <!-- END ROW -->


                                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Whats could be the reason why on the second upload the image does not display on the front page?

Comment: Did you check the output (in Dev Tools, or page source) what the image `src` of the second image actually contains? You could also verify adding a line for `debug_log('Repeater row '.get_row_index().' contains image: '.json_encode($image));` below getting the sub fields. This way you could check the debug log for what is actually returned by ACF.

Comment: Where do you mean the second image?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below:

```html
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if( have_rows('latest1') ): ?>
 <div class="row">
  <?php while( have_rows('latest1') ): the_row(); 
   $image = get_sub_field('image');
   $title = get_sub_field('title');
   $news = get_sub_field('news');
   $more = get_sub_field('more');
   $date = get_sub_field('date');
  ?>
  <!-- REPEATING SEGMENT -->
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <a href="wrk-AboutUS.html" class="img-news-container">
    <img src="<?php echo $image["url"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
   </a>
  </div>
  <div id="primary3" class="content-area col-md-7 no-padding-right">
   <main id="main3" class="site-main " >
    <article class="item-lastest-news itemBlogList">
     <div class="">
      <a href="wrk-AboutUS.html"><h4 class="title-news"><?php echo $title; ?></h4></a>
      <div class="">
       <span class="dates" style="color:green;"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
      </div>
      <p> <?php echo $news; ?></p>
      <a class="continueReading" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><span style="color: brown;">Continue Reading</span></a>
     <hr>
     </div><!-- End Text box -->
    </article><!-- End Arcicle -->
   </main>
  </div>
  <!-- REPEATING SEGMENT -->
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 </div> <!-- END ROW -->
<?php endif; ?>
```